# PHPActiveRecord validates_uniqueness_of not working

Tags: php, activerecord, model, php-7, phpactiverecord

I am currently getting the following error in my **User** model.

```
Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

Details

Type: ActiveRecord\UndefinedPropertyException
Message: Undefined property: User->Array in /var/www/public_html/devsite/vendor/php-activerecord/php-activerecord/lib/Model.php on line 521
File: /var/www/public_html/devsite/vendor/php-activerecord/php-activerecord/lib/Model.php
Line: 521
```

**My model only crashes the program when I add the line below to it.**

```
static $validates_uniqueness_of = array(
      'username'
 );
```

If I remove the line above then the program runs again just fine.  So I know it has something to do with this.

According to the documentation this should indeed be the format. 
(http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Validations#validates_uniqueness_of)

Reference to the validate function from the library is below:

Line 563 --
https://github.com/jpfuentes2/php-activerecord/blob/master/lib/Validations.php

**I'm using PHP Version 7.0.15-0 on ubuntu0.16.04.4**

If this is truly a bug, does anyone have any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I created a complete solution now.  Anyone who can improve this is welcome.

First create a separate file and call it uniquecheck.php.

Inside it put this trait code.

```
trait uniquecheck {
    //@JA - This function can do single and multi-unique checks.
    //@JA - This is programmed to be replaced at a later date when validates_uniqueness_of is fixed (http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Validations#validates_uniqueness_of)
    //@JA - EXAMPLES
    //SINGLE    -- array('name','message' => 'Can't do this')
    //MULTIPLE  -- array( array('name1','name2'), 'message' => 'can't do this and that together')
    //@JA - To be clear multiple does not mean 2 different uniques but a unique on 2 columns.  Just use this function twice for 2 separate unique checks.
    //@JA -  Refer to (https://github.com/jpfuentes2/php-activerecord/issues/336)
    public function uniquecheck($rules = array()) {  
        //@JA - If its an array use the MULTIPLE method

        $dirty = $this->dirty_attributes();//@JA - Get list of attributes that have been modified since loading the model

        if(is_array($rules[0])){
            //@JA - Generate first part of condition string
            $uniques = $rules[0];
            foreach($uniques as $unique){
                $conditionstring .= "$unique = ? AND "; 
            }
            $conditionstring = substr($conditionstring, 0, -5);

            $dirtyfound = false;

            //@JA - Then generate the array we will use for the conditions
            $conditionarray['conditions'][] = $conditionstring;
            foreach($uniques as $unique){
                $conditionarray['conditions'][] = $this->read_attribute($unique);
                if(array_key_exists($unique, $dirty)){
                    $dirtyfound = true;
                }
            }

            if ($dirtyfound == true) { //@JA - If one of the parts that makes the record unique is dirty then...
                try {
                    //@JA - Whatever the primary key currently is return the object for that.  This will be the object reference for what is not modified
                    $currently = Self::find($this->id);
                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    $currently = false;
                }

                foreach($uniques as $unique){
                    if ((
                        (is_object($currently) && $currently->$unique != $this->$unique)
                        || !is_object($currently)
                    ) && static::exists($conditionarray))
                        $this->errors->add($unique, $rules['message']);
                }   
            }
        }else{ //@JA - Otherwise use the SINGLE method

            $unique = $rules[0];
            if (array_key_exists($unique, $dirty)) { //@JA - If the value we are checking to be unique has been modified...
                try {
                    //@JA - Whatever the primary key currently is return the object for that.  This will be the object reference for what is not modified
                    $currently = Self::find($this->id);
                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    $currently = false;
                }

                //@JA - The dirty attributes array simply contains fields that have been set by our code.
                //@JA - Ergo if we have re-applied the same value to our model, it will be classed as dirty even though it has not changed
                //@JA - If $currently was returned as an object type AND its original value does not equal the current dirty value of the property on the model
                //@JA - OR If the object returned was not an object (meaning it does not currently exists in the database)...
                //@JA - OR it could mean that the table is just empty for the first time... Thus
                //@JA - AND if the dirty value of the unique was found to exist then a unique was found.
                if ((
                    (is_object($currently) && $currently->$unique != $this->$unique)
                    || !is_object($currently)
                ) && static::exists(array($unique => $this->$unique)))
                    $this->errors->add($unique, $rules['message']);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use this in your model just use the statement 'use uniquecheck;' after including the php file with reference to the trait.  For example...

```
require_once('traits/uniquecheck.php');//@JA - Helper to check if values are unique
class Client extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    use uniquecheck;
    public function validate() {
         $this->uniquecheck(array(array('company_id','contactfirstname','contactlastname', 'contactphonenumber', 'contactaddress'),'message' => 'Can\'t have duplicate client.'));
     }

}
```

The above shows an example of how to check a multiple unique.  This will work for **new records** **AND for** **editing records** since the trait is smart to know which fields are dirty or not.

If you are not using a multi-unique it works just like this instead.

```
public function validate() {
    $this->uniquecheck(array('username','message' => 'Username already in use'));
}
```

I copied the format that they use on PHPActiveRecords documentation so it should work exactly the same now.

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score -1):

public static $validates_uniqueness_of = array(
      'username'
 )

Answer (score -1):

shot in the dark:

```
static $validates_uniqueness_of = array(
      array('username')
 );
```

Comment: Nope this didn't work, good try though, I think this is a bug from my research that maybe never got fixed.  I have a temporary work around I found, but still not sure how to handle multiple uniques